# Finding probability of specific income amount

Tags: probability

You own an ice cream shop which sells cones with up to three scoops of ice cream. 
0.75 of the customers order one scoop. 0.15 order two scoops, and the rest order three scoops.

If you charge 1 dollar for one scoop, 2 dollars for two scoops, and 3 dollars for three scoops, and there is no tax or other fees, what is your expected value for the next ten customers?

Let Y be the amount of money paid by the customers.

Find P(Y = $15)

I found E(Y)

$$ E(Y) = (0.75)$1 + (0.15)$2 + (0.1)($3) = $1.35 $$

How would I approach finding P(Y = $15)?

And how would I find the number of customers until I'd sold one cone of each type?

I'm sure this is a simple question, and I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for:
$$ [x^{15}]\left(\frac{3}{4}x+\frac{3}{20}x^2+\frac{1}{10}x^3\right)^{10} = \frac{104103387}{819200000} = \color{red}{12,7\%}.$$

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer for me Jack? I can't follow it

Comment: I'm sure you're right, could you please help me understand how you knew to do this?

Comment: @HaroldKliner: The income is a Markov chain: probabilities in such a context are computed through standard generating-functions techniques. Here, the arrival of a customer is simulated by the multiplication by a fixed polynomial. The coefficients of such a polynomial encode the transition probabilities and the exponents encode the income.

Comment: Ah, I haven't learned anything remotely like that, so I'm guessing there must be another way. I'll keep looking. Thanks!

Comment: @HaroldKliner: Yes, you can just count in how many ways you can represent $15$ as a sum of exactly $10$ integers among $\{1,2,3\}$, then give a weight to every representation, according to its probability. Then, finally, realize you are just computing the coefficient of $x^{15}$ in the tenth power of a certain polynomial, like I did. An upvote would have been kind, anyway.